# How do I add a dataframe column whose values are derived from other column values?

Tags: r

I have a United States Census dataset where each observation has binary values for Black, Hispanic, and NotWhiteBlackOrHispanic. I'd like to derive a White value (1 where Black, Hispanic, and NotWhiteBlackOrHispanic are 0; 0 otherwise) and append it to my existing dataframe.

I unsuccessfully tried

```
census$white<-if(census$black==0 && census$hispanic==0 && census$notwbh==0){1}else{0})
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
census$white <- with(census, 
   !any(Black,Hispanic ,noWhiteBlackOrHispanic)))
```

The 'any' function should coerce numeric to logical and this should be quite efficient.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
ifelse(census$black==0 && census$hispanic==0 && census$notwbh==0,1,0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ifelse`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html)

```
census$white<-ifelse(census$black==0 && census$hispanic==0 && census$notwbh==0,1,0)
```